# ArgumentError when trying to pass nested parameters in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

When I'm trying to execute the following line

```
post :create, user: Fabricate.attributes_for(:user)
```

I get this error message  `ArgumentError: unknown keyword: user`.
Here's the code I was originally trying to run:

```
describe 'POST create' do
   context 'with valid input' do
     it 'creates the user' do
       post :create, user: Fabricate.attributes_for(:user)
       expect(User.count).to eq(1)
     end
   end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the StackOverflow markdown parser uses a four space indentation instead of fenced code blocks (```) like on Github. Use (ctrl/command + k) to indent code blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the [changes in Rails 5](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/04/19/changes-to-test-controllers-in-rails-5.html) is that the testing request methods accept only keyword arguments instead of passing any arbitrary hash option as a param which was the behavior in Rails 4.

```
post :create, params: { user: Fabricate.attributes_for(:user) }
```